# Which simple document management system?

Tags: content-management-system, document, ecm

For a small-medium sized NGO with little money, I am looking for a simple document management system (NOT a Web CMS). The requirements are relatively simple :

- Web based
- Free (as in free beer) or very cheap, and better if it is open-source too
- Able to store electronic documents (Word, PDF, ...) and scanned paper documents (in PDF/jpeg/whatever image format)
- Along with some metadata : name of the doc, project/department to which it belongs, author, date, place, some identifiying code, a short description,...

Optional but nice :

- Versioning
- Indexing/search inside the word/pdf/text/... documents

From my research on the net and other threads on SO, I am down to these 3 products :

- KnowledgeTree (installed locally, not the SAAS)
- Alfresco
- Nuxeo DM

With a preference for KT, the other 2 feelinbg like overkill for our simple requirements. I am also looking at MS Sharepoint Foundation (ex-Sharepoint Services) but it would mean buying a Windows Server license which I don't think they will want to.

Can somebody give me some feedback about these products, especially KT ? Which one would you choose (or avoid) ? Is there any other suitable solution that I missed ? Any info welcome !

Answer (score 3):

sorry, i don't know KT but is installed and used Alfresco some time ago at my old job. it's the pure hell to install, but if you got it running, its great. i never had any problems (except installing, but maybe i was just too dumb for that) and it fulfills all requirements you posted (the optional ones, too).

**EDIT:**

i wrote my own litte, 1-site-10-point-tutorial for installing (on ubuntu) because the tutorial in the official wiki wasn't realy helping. it's in german, but i saw your're from switzerland, so if you would need help, i could send this to you (after finding it again...).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the doc proposition. But I won't be installing the system personnaly, probably somebody in Bolivia will, who doesn't speak German ;)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from versioning, and interpreting office document (although both are planned features) [Mayan EDMS](https://www.mayan-edms.com) might fill the bill.

UPDATE:

These features have been added.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this NGO solution and case studies at http://www.docuvantage.com/non-profit-document-management-and-compliance. You can do a free trial and you will find it is very affordable and easy for the end users. It provides the functionality that you need out of the box while giving you the option to add more as you need.

Comment: The product looks interesting but I can't seem to find any pricing information on their (your?) website...